# Pentadiagonal Matrix in OpenCV

Tags: matlab, models, contour, opencv3.0

I'm trying to implement the active contour models algorithm with c++ and opencv in VisualStudio.
I'm having trouble creating a pentadiagonal matrix, that is a matrix with the five main diagonals with values and zeros in the rest of the matrix.
I've already implemented this in MatLab, that came out like this:

```
K = diag(repmat(a,1,n));
K = K + diag(repmat(b,1,n-1),1) + diag(repmat(b,1,n-1),-1)...
    + diag(b,n-1) + diag(b,-n+1);
K = K + diag(repmat(c,1,n-2),2) + diag(repmat(c,1,n-2),-2)...
+ diag([c c],n-2) + diag([c c],-n+2);
```

How do I do the same thing in opencv?
Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer. It should work as expected. If you provide in your question also the values for a,b,c,n I can double check my code. Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the Matlab functions `repmat` and `diag` as in the code below.

Then you can write the OpenCV code as in Matlab. The only difference is that you cannot concatenate 2 matrices with `[c c]`, but you should use `repmat(c, 2, 1)`, or `repmat(c,1,2)` for `[c; c]`.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

Mat repmat(const Mat& src, int nx, int ny)
{
    return repeat(src, nx, ny);
}

Mat diag(const Mat& src, int k=0)
{
    // src must be a row or column matrix
    //CV_Assert(src.rows == 1 || src.cols == 2);
    int n = src.rows * src.cols;

    Mat1d _src;
    src.convertTo(_src, CV_64F);

    // Create output matrix of correct dimension
    int dim = n + abs(k);
    Mat1d _dst(dim, dim, double(0.0));


    // Select the ranges where to put src data
    Range rrows;
    Range rcols;
    if (k >= 0)
    {
        rrows = Range(0, n);
        rcols = Range(k, k+n);
    }
    else
    {
        rrows = Range(-k, -k + n);
        rcols = Range(0, n);
    }

    // Create square n x n submatrix
    Mat1d sub(_dst(rrows, rcols));

    // Put data on the diagonal of the submatrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        sub(i, i) = _src(i);
    }

    Mat dst;
    _dst.convertTo(dst, src.type());
    return dst;
}

int main()
{
    Mat a;
    Mat b;
    Mat c;
    int n;

    // ... init a, b, c, n

    Mat K;
    K = diag(repmat(a, 1, n));
    K = K + diag(repmat(b, 1, n - 1), 1) + diag(repmat(b, 1, n - 1), -1) + diag(b, n - 1) + diag(b, -n + 1);
    K = K + diag(repmat(c, 1, n - 2), 2) + diag(repmat(c, 1, n - 2), -2) + diag(repmat(b, 2, 1), n - 2) + diag(repmat(b, 2, 1), -n + 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! a, b and c are actually float types and not matrices. They are values that will be inputed by the user. Will the "repeat" function still work?

Comment: Never mind, I can do with a, b and c beeing matrices. Thanks again, the code works greatly!